# How to find how many times a word is repeated in a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to write a program that asks the user for some text and then checks how many times the word "owl" is repeated in there. The program should also count the word if it's included in another one. Ex "hellowl" should return; The word "owl" was repeated 1 time.

I've tried using .find() but I get an error message so if anyone could tell me how to implement it correctly I would really appreciate it.
My current code works but doesn't count if owl is said inside another word as mentioned in the example above

```
user = str(input("Enter some text: "))

user = user.lower()
user = user.split()

# Counts how many times the word "owl" is said
def owl_count(user):
    count = 0
    for x in user:
        if x == "owl":
            count = count + 1
    return count        

print "There were " + str(owl_count(user)) + " words that contained \"owl\"."
```

If the user enters " I like eatingowls" the output should be "There were 1 word that contained "owl" but instead it returns 0

Comment: ```str.count("owl")```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `split` you will only get a match if `owl` is used as a word and not if it is inside a word. What you can do is the following

```
user = str(input("Enter some text: "))
user = user.lower()
# Counts how many times the word "owl" is said
def owl_count(user):
    count = 0
    for x in range(len(user)-2):
        if user[x:x+3] == "owl":
            count = count + 1
    return count        
print("There were " + str(owl_count(user)) + " words that contained \"owl\".")
```

Or just use python's `count`

```
def owl_count(user):
    return user.count('owl')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

user = "owlfdfdfowldfdfdowdffowl"

x = user.count("owl")              # Best
y = len(re.findall("owl", user))   
z = len(user.split("owl")) - 1     

print(x, y, z) #3 3 3
```

Answer (score -2):

The code has `if x == "owl"`, therefore the code only counts words that are *equal* to "owl".

If you want to check for words that *contain* "owl", use `if "owl" in x` instead.

Comment: The entire function can be replaced with ```str.count("owl")```

Comment: @JoshuaNixon Yes, but I thought it would be helpful to explain the behavior of the original code.

Comment: If you replace ```if x == "owl"``` with ```if "owl" in x``` like you suggest then it still won't work as intended.

Comment: @JoshuaNixon The text output of the program is `There were N words that contained "owl"`, therefore it should not care about multiple occurrences within a word.  Granted this seems to be in conflict with other parts of the question -- so let's chalk this up to poor requirements.